# Есть ли в go аналог cv-qualifier в параметрах функции?

Tags: golang

Есть ли в го возможность передать в функцию указатель на объект, но при этом запретить функции его изменять?

Также можно ли запретить методу изменять поля структуры?

Что на плюсах делается с помощью

```cpp
bool is_negative(int const & ptr) {
    return (ptr < 0) ? true : false;
}
```

и

```cpp
int SomeClass::get_value() const {...}
```

соответственно.

(Понятно что в примере 1 это смысла не имеет, но на месте `int`'а мог быть какой-нибудь большой класс, объекты которого копировать не хочется.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет.  Это одна из возможностей, которые авторы языка намеренно
пропустили при его создании.  Из
[*FAQ*](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Why_doesnt_Go_have_feature_X):

> Every language contains novel features and omits someone's favorite
> feature. Go was designed with an eye on felicity of programming, speed
> of compilation, orthogonality of concepts, and the need to support
> features such as concurrency and garbage collection. Your favorite
> feature may be missing because it doesn't fit, because it affects
> compilation speed or clarity of design, or because it would make the
> fundamental system model too difficult.
>
> If it bothers you that Go is missing feature X, please forgive us and
> investigate the features that Go does have. You might find that they
> compensate in interesting ways for the lack of X.

Конкретно решение об отсутствии неизменяемых значений всегда было одним
из спорных элементов дизайна, и на Гитхабе до сих пор много предложений
добавить их в язык.  (`const`, который сейчас есть
в *Go*, это про константы времени компиляции, а не про неизменяемые
значения; разница есть.)

Интересно, что в диалекте языка *C*, который Роб Пайк сотоварищи
использовали в ОС *Plan 9 From Bell Labs*, ключевое слово
*const* тоже ничего не делало и по сути игнорировалось.